# Why unnecessarily initialize a variable?

Tags: java

We know that there is a default of each primitive data type in Java(For e.g.:- The default value of double data type is 0.0d.).Then if we want the value of a variable(suppose *double a*) to be equal to the default value,why should we need to specify the value as:

```
double a=0.0d;
```

Why can't we not just use the default value of the variable anywhere as its default value is the same as the value we want to assign?

Comment: is it local or global variable? even if it's a global variable there is no harm in initializing it to the default value. one could argue it provides more intent.

Answer (score 2):

Different types do have default values that will be assigned to any unassigned fields of that type. However, this does not apply to local variables, as shown in the [Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) [§4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value
>   before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment
>   (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite
>   assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

I speculate that this is to make your code clearer. In a method, you would want readers of your code know what each and every variable's value is, instead of relying on the reader remembering facts like "a `boolean`s default value is `false`". Since what you are writing is likely an algorithm of some sort, you want to write it as clearly as possible for other people.

In fields however, this is not required. I think this is because you are not describing a set of steps to do something. Instead, you are just saying that this object has some property. The semantics are a little different here.

Answer (score 0):

As per Java language specification *local variable must be initilized before use*. Let's see why would such rule would have been made for local variables and not for instance variables.

Compiler tries to eliminate as much errors as possible during compile time only thereby making the application runtime more stable. For this it detects the issues it can at compile time and throws compile time exceptions.

Non final instance variables can be initilized in constructor (which may be multiple, overloaded) or in one of the methods of the class. Before using such a variable compiler does not complain as it assumes programmer would have provided the initial value in some method or constructor. The initilization depends on run time of the application as during run time a method can be invoked which does the initilization and hence compile time detection if value is not provided by the programmer is not possible and hence compiler chooses the safe option of allowing usuage and provides the default value in case method or constructor which handles the initilization is not invoked.

Non final local variable can only be initilized within it's method. There is not much point of making a non final variable if user wants to use the default value. It makes more sense to use the value directly or use a final keyword. If a non final local variable has been used then compiler forces the user to provide the initial value which may or may not be the default value.

For final fields both instance level and local, compiler forces the user to provide the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise only local variables or class level variables declared final as per the java language spec. They won't be initialised with default values.